# Background image aligned left

Tags: html, css

Let's say i have a css class called 'author' like in this code :

```
.author {
    background:url('img/user91.png');
    background-size:10px 10px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color:#62c6ff;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

and html :

```
<p class="author"><a href="#">@jimmy</a></p>
```

I want @jimmy to be displayed in a p and in the left side of @jimmy to appear the image background. 
[image: this is an example picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add

```
background-position: 0 0; padding-left: 10px /*this should be equal to image width*/
```

to .author class

Hope this helps!

do you need any fiddle link to show this up?

Answer (score 2):

You should use background-position to place the image on the left side:

> background-position: left center;

or

> background-position: 0 0;

And then play with padding to place the link to the author:

> padding-left: 15px;

Answer (score 0):

simply use this

```
 `background:url("img/user91.png") no-repeat right 0px; `
```